# Is there a way that I could use a vector instead of this for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying loop through a bunch of files in R and access info in each one. Needless to say, the loop is unbearably slow. Is there a way I could vectorize this?

```
library("rjson")

all_files=list.files(path="~/p/a/t/h", recursive = TRUE)

for(i in seq_along(all_files)) {
    temp = fromJSON(file = all_files[i])
    if (length(temp$tags) != 0){
        songTags <- c(songTags, temp$tags)
        songTrack_id <- c(songTrack_id, temp$track_id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Growing objects in a loop is usually very expensive/slow. You can use `lapply`/`sapply`.

```
all_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_files, function(x) {
                temp = jsonlite::fromJSON(file = x)
                if(length(temp$tags)) 
                   list(tags = temp$tags, track_id = temp$track_id)
            }))
```

Or a shorter option using `purrr`'s `map_df`

```
all_data <- map_df(all_files, ~{
               temp = jsonlite::fromJSON(file = .x)
               if(length(temp$tags)) 
                  list(tags = temp$tags, track_id = temp$track_id)
               })
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```r
rawdat <- lapply(all_files, fromJSON)
hastags <- sapply(rawdat, function(x) "tags" %in% names(rawdat))
if (any(hastags)) {
  songTags <- unlist(lapply(rawdat[hastags], `[[`, "tags"))
  songTracks <- unlist(lapply(rawdat[hastags], `[[`, "track_id"))
}
```